# URL doesn't change on sub-pages or when leaving site

Tags: url, masking

I'm new to the world of webmasters, so I haven't been able to appropriately search for an answer.  I don't know the keywords that describe my situation.

I registered [hallienoelle.com](http://hallienoelle.com/) and the `.net` version through GoDaddy and set up forwarding with masking to [hallienoelle2.wpengine.com](http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/).

When you go to the `.com` or `.net`, it takes you to the homepage with no slashes or anything after it.  If you click on a different page, it takes you to that page, but doesn't change the url.  It still says `hallienoelle.com` with no slashes or anything after it.

The *most worrisome* part is that if someone clicks an external link **my URL is still in the address bar.**

For example, clicking the *Powered by Wordpress* link at the bottom takes you to `wordpress.org`, but the address bar still shows `hallienoelle.com` with no slashes or anything after it .

Did I do something wrong in setting up GoDaddy forwarding or is it a Wordpress/WPEngine configuration issue?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to PatomaS I know how to fix the external link problem. I still am unsure of how to get the directory/folder/webpage to display after the `.com` like so:

1. Go to `hallienoelle.com` (and see the content from `hallienoelle2.wpengine.com`)
2. Click a link, like `About Us`
3. This should take you to `hallienoelle.com/?page_id=11` (and you see the content from `hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/?page_id=11`)
4. **But,** currently it still shows just `hallienoelle.com` even though you are looking at the `?page_id=11` page.

Do I have to go through all my internal links and hard-code something like `<a href="hallienoelle.com/?page_id=11" target="_top">About Us</a>`?

This seems inefficient and error prone. I'm probably just misunderstanding something.

**UPDATE 2:**
WPEngine also gives me the option of forwarding to `http://198.58.98.52/` and I (think) it reads the requested URL from the header and serves my content.

I add this because as I've been reading someone said redirects to `mysite.example.com` are generally used for free hosting providers and are looked down upon.  I use `hallienoelle2.wpengine.com` because it is recommended on `http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-configure-your-dns/` under the heading `Setting up a subdomain`.

Comment: Do you want to keep your URL without wpengine? Can you move all your content to your site, and not use wpengine?

Comment: @PatomaS I'm intentionally using WPEngine because they're very good about Wordpress security and I can focus my limited time on other aspects. "Do I want to keep my URL without wpengine?" I'm sorry, I don't understand.  Could you rephrase that?

Comment: No need to rephrase, you already answered. If you want to keep the site on wpengine, but show the other url, then masking is a good option, but you have to take care of the external links, read my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking you code, we can see that you have this:

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>
```

I suppose that is the masking part of the setting on GoDaddy that you mention.

Which means that you are using frames on your site. All the content is on the lower frame, the one that says `<frame frameborder="0" noresize />`. and your links are normal one, like this:

```
Powered by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org">WordPress</a>
```

you have to change that link to something like this

```
Powered by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org" target="_top">WordPress</a>
```

or

```
Powered by <a href="http://www.wordpress.org" target="_parent">WordPress</a>
```

Although both options work slightly different, there is no difference in your actual situation.

**Update**

Since all the pages/resources from `http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/` are inside the frame in `hallienoelle.com`, you can not see any change in the URL bar.

All the links from `http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/` will work normally, but the idea of the masking, is to keep the `hallienoelle.com` on the URL, all the time.

When you edit your code or pages on `http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/` or when you add more content there, don't worry about the other address, just do all the editing and linking as if `hallienoelle.com` didn't exist. In fact, for `http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/`, `hallienoelle.com` doesn't exist. It's just a concept on our mind as users.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works perfectly for external links. It also works for hard-coded internal links like `http://hallienoelle2.wpengine.com/?page_id=13`, but that is sub-optimal.  At this point, we (you) have established it's because of GoDaddy's frames.  Should I keep searching and/or contact WPEngine for a way to have them display `hallienoelle.com/?page_id=13` or is that not possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want to have your content on `hallienoelle2.wpengine.com` but show it on `wpengine.com`, your  easiest option is to use frames, as you are doing now. All the links from `hallienoelle2.wpengine.com` without a `target="_top"` are going to be on the frame, which is what you want. If you want any specific link to behave different, please update the question and explain what you want so we can answer that.

Comment: I updated the question.  I don't know if you get notified about that, so I'm commenting.  Thank you for your help again!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would upvote you, but I don't have enough rep.